# SonarQube New Code Definition is working wrong

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

We were using Sonarqube Enterprise Edition and it’s version is 9.2 and we upgraded it to 9.3 yesterday. So we always use latest version for Enterprise Edition.

I think Sonarqube New Code definition is working wrong. I will try to tell you with our example.

You can see what our project’s New Code definition is.

[image: Project settings on Sonarqube]

I think Sonarqube should calculate difference code from the previous version. But it did not do that.

P.S. We scan our repository’s develop branch on Sonarqube every night as scheduled. So the previous version is yesterday’s scan.

We work with feature branches in our repository. Basically, we create new feature branch from develop, then we develop our features in the feature branch. Sometimes it takes one or more weeks. We did a lot of commits in this duration. After we finish developing, we merge the feature branch to develop. And that night, Sonarqube scan develop branch again. I think the merged feature branch’s codes is all new code. But Sonarqube only considers commits made that day(last day). Previous commits’ codes are not shown in New Code reports.

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

**Update 1:**

I tried to fix the Sonarqube Project’s version nubmer. After that, the New Code definition shows as “Started 5 days ago”. As you can see the below image. It means it takes 5 days period.

[image]

But I tried to tell before. I want to see all merged branches, commits to develop in new code report for every day. Is there any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't offer a solution, just reporting that we have the same problem (using an SVN-based repository with SonarQube 8.9 LTS). We did not have these problems back in SonarQube 6.7, where we were using an individual SQ-project per branch. It seems the analyzer has become too clever for its own good, since it now compares the commit date of the individual changed lines in the original branch, instead of using the commit date of the revision in the main branch that it got merged into.